# Why should I learn modern category theory if my interest mainly is structured sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, category-theory, big-picture

A long time ago I studied mathematics at the University of Stockholm. I had a romantic view of modern algebra and manage to make the first two algebra courses by self studies in order to immediately study homological algebra, Galois theory and such topics. That is not the best way to study. Later as a graduate student I did rather well - until the gaps in my basic knowledge and abilities began to affect too much. Then I stopped focusing on mathematics about 35 years ago.

I did self studies in category theory because we were supposed to do that and because it was a good idea. Category theory worked fine with the mathematics evolved at 1950 or so. The universal definitions and duality simplified a lot of mathematics as tensor products and injective/projective modules etc and the functors opened new possibilities.

The last 40 years or so the interest in and the development of category theory has exploded and seems nowaday be very abstract but also very consistent.

My question is, what modern category theory could be    interesting for a person mainly interested in the mathematics concerning structured sets?

The bounty will soon expire and there is 50+ in reputation to earn - aren't there anything to express on this topic?

Comment: To be more clear: By multicateries, do you mean $2$-categories and above?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft To my knowledge nobody uses the word [multicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multicategory) for anything other than a colored operad... And if the question is really about higher categories then I'm even more baffled because very many people are already interested in them, even more so than multicategories.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Ahh, thanks (I had not encountered the term before, but then, my view of category theory is somewhat narrow).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft To be fair it's possible that your guess was right and OP really meant higher categories, since the question is relatively confused already and multicategories seemingly appear out of nowhere.

Comment: Vote to close as unclear, since there is even doubt what subject is asked about.

Comment: I thought you guys where eager to share your knowledge.

Comment: People are eager to share their knowledge, but you have to ask a clear and precise question first... As we can now see, @Tobias was right and you weren't talking about multicategories at all (why use that word without looking it up?). Now, this question is too broad, it's not reasonable to ask for motivation for category *and* higher category theory! If you want category theory [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29152), if you want higher category [see this](http://mathoverflow.net/q/185997). This is another problem with your question: it doesn't appear you did any research...

Comment: The question was already clear and precise enough, even if the english phrasing isn't the natural/native. With a minimum of charity, the (original) question reads as "what are reasons for someone interested in the mathematics of *structured sets* to study category theory or multicategories?" This is not broad; it's about the relevance of category theory to a particular (I think Bourbakian) way of looking at and thinking about mathematics.

Comment: Do I even need to comment on forcing the OP to change "multicategories" to "higher categories"? It's not clear to me that that's what he meant at all, or that he changed his question out of any other hope than to appease your fetish for jargon, after which you go around and decry the question as too broad!

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Given that he changed it after being asked what he meant, it is pretty clear that he actually meant higher categories rather than multicategories.

Comment: First of all, the higher categories only got introduced into the discussion because Tobias assumed that's what the question is about instead of looking up what multicategories are and whether they are related to higher category theory. Second, multicategories are implicitly part of the 40 years of development of category theory that the OP missed; they don't "appear out of nowhere". Third, multicategories are more directly relevant to structured sets (e.g. through multi-linear algebra) than higher categories are, and you all are ignoring the **structured sets** part of the question.

Comment: Fourth, the change from "multicategory" to "higher categories" happened *after* the question was put on hold as far as I can tell from the history... but that's not the point. The point is that the question is only broad if you ignore that it's explicitly about how modern developments in category theory (such as multicategories) could be relevant to understanding structured sets, and that it's not about general reasons to care about modern developments in category theory (such as higher categories).

Comment: @VladimirSotirov, thanks for your support, but the truth is that I can't distinguish between the ideas of modern what-so-ever-category theory. It seems very complicated to learn, in the sense that you don't know where to begin. It's like a never-ending simultan multi recursion: to know this idea you have to know that idea and to know that idea you have to ... Idrissi is right about my lacking effort but I would need motivation even to make that effort in the maze of modern category theory. It shouldn't be to difficult to understand the level of my knowledge/ignorance.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi you have your views on what's "acceptable", I have mine. I wasn't trying to twist your words, I am disagreeing that multicategories came out of nowhere in *the post*, but that's not the point (although I am irked by requiring beginners, and especially possibly amateur beginners, to navigate the category theoretic literature on their own, and to consider the lack of that effort as reason to dismiss their question). The point I want to make is that the question was never about modern category theory in general, but about its specific relation to the structured sets point of view.

Comment: e.g. "why would I learn modern category theory if using structured sets works just fine for me, what would I have to gain?"

Comment: For a start I'd recommend to browse something on the subject, say, the [Intro to Tom Leinster's book](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049)  That's could be done quite quickly. It has a motivation section. Then you'd have a more clear idea what you might want to ask.

Comment: @quid. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Which basic knowledge exactly were you missing if I may ask? Doing self-study seems a fine method to me to gain the similar knowledge? Were you missing basic knowledge in algebra, or other disciplines such as analysis or geometry?

Comment: @Sigurd: it was mostly analysis but also group theory. Self study is right but not hasty and sloppy self studies. One must do a lot of exercises etc.

Comment: @Lehs: Thanks. I'm in a similar situation now, do you have any advice on how to avoid having gaps in your knowledge later on? Any particular courses or areas that are important? I'm self-studying some courses now, but it seems a bit worrying that this might not be enough to learn it properly. I'm a bit surprised that you did very well on advanced courses such as Galois theory and homological algebra, but still find holes in your basic knowledge that are too large to patch, how is this possible?

Comment: I didn't do that good result in Galois theory. I got the big picture with automorphism groups (wich was very interesting) but needed more concrete knowledge of specific groups etc. I found homological algebra and algebraic topology to be very interesting and much more simple. I'ts abstract but I had rather good knowledge about modules and training in diagram chase. It's all about not to rush and to do the exercises. I also think that certain topics as group theory and number theory are more complex, while homology looks complex but are rather straight.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the most compelling answer to the question:

> My question is, what modern category theory could be interesting for a person mainly interested in the mathematics concerning structured sets?

is just that a great deal of modern algebraic geometry, as a result of Grothendieck and others, makes heavy use of category theory. Here, I'm basically replacing "structured sets" with "rings, fields and modules." However, the study of groups and monoids has also been immensely impacted by category theory. In particular, category theory has played a really large role in representation theory.

If "structured sets" also includes topological spaces then there's even more category theory that ends up being relevant. And of course, topological spaces, and the study of their invariants, are important in things mentioned above like algebraic geometry and representation theory.

One problem with your question is that it's immensely broad. You're basically asking "How is category theory used in algebra?" And well, the answer at this point is almost "In what cases is it not used?"

My suggestion, if you want to have some sense of what category theory is all about, is pick up Saunders Mac Lane's book and force yourself to learn the foundations (e.g. categories, functors, natural transformations) from a purely formal point of view, and then read about the examples. Then pick some topic you like (e.g. ring theory, or representation theory) and ask a more specific question about category theory in, say, representation theory. Again, for any of this to make any sense at all, you'll have to have a pretty good grip on whatever topic it is you're interested in. Category theory tends to produce "large scale" structural theorems, and so if you're not familiar enough with a topic to be interested in how all of its pieces fit together, it (in my opinion) will be very hard to motivate category theory.

However, after writing all of this, and then reading through the comments above a bit more, I see that someone has really already provided you with an answer, which is [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29152/motivation-and-use-for-category-theory), so that's probably a pretty good place to start.

Comment: I disagree with your characterization of the question as, "How is category theory used in algebra?". That's probably an oversimplification of the question which I thought to be along the lines expressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862995/why-should-i-learn-modern-category-theory-if-my-interest-mainly-is-structured-se#comment3818784_1862995).

Comment: The wide applications of Category Theory doesn't make it more significant than that of "structured sets" (which I think should be made more precise @Lehs) if there is not some advantages of using categories over that of "structured sets".

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, but I used Saunders-McLane during my self studies and with modern category theory I rather ment the developement the last 30 years.

Comment: Ok well, I think that I really don't understand what the question is asking. Is it asking for a defense of the use of category theory? I think that's hardly necessary. Is it asking for an encyclopedic description of the uses of category theory in modern mathematics? I'm pretty sure that is the definition of being "too broad."

Comment: @Jonathan I had no big problem with the original category theory, but it seems difficult to overview the modern topics and undetstand it's connection to classical mathematics. Maybe someone should  make a map and a manual. I'm sure there are certain developement for the sake of it's own, but some might be useful also in the case of sets with structures.